# flutter navigation two pages (classes) the back button

Tags: android, navigation, flutter

I have two pages in my app (2 class )
I navigate between them by drawer

The page consist of list view and navigate to detail page

I made an arrow icon  in detail page  to back me to the listview

**My Problem:**
In  my  second class  when I  Click the back button of the android device it back  to the list of the first class

I used the following code in the arrow back on detail page:

---

```
 appBar: AppBar(
     leading: new IconButton( icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
     onPressed: (){
         Navigator.pop(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => myapp()));
     }),
```

---

The arrow  return me  to the correct class   but the back button of the device  return me to the  first class

How can I  make it  navigate to the same class?

Comment: You don't have to implement this functionality. `Scaffold` will handle this automatically. Remove `leading` Widget from `AppBar`.

Comment: I remove  it  but  still    in my  second page which have the same one page  ( list  and navigate ti detail page )  when i back from my detail page in my second page (class)  it  back  to the  list of the first  class    not  the  second      i hope  u understood me

Comment: Edit your question and post code so that I can understand better.

Answer (score 0):

Use Only `Navigator.pop(context);` It will automatically navigate to the previous page. Don't Use any class.